# Autoupdate VIM Plugins?

Tags: vim, macvim

Is it possible to update vim plugins automatically?

Comment: If you use Janus, this is do-able simply by running rake in ~/.vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=642) vim plugin seems to do what you are after, though it hasn't been updated in a while.  Never used it, but the author has written a "few" vim plugins in the past.

Comment: Used it, and although probably it can be made to work, I've personally categorized it under "asking for trouble".

Comment: Tested it with a few vim plugins. Works great for me! Thanks for the tip. (I had tested this plugin some years ago... without any success...)

Answer (score 3):

To provide an up to date answer to this old question, [**Vundle**](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)
works really great. It simulates the ruby `bundle` gem, you simply configure your Bundles in `.vimrc` and then run `:BundleInstall!` inside vim.

Answer (score 2):

[vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905) has the function *:UpdateAddons [{name} ...]* which when called with no arguments updates all installed addons.

Comment: Not all *installed*, but all *active* and additionally vim-addon-manager-known-repositories.

Answer (score 0):

My operating systems ([Archlinux](http://www.archlinux.org)) has a bunch of packages containing vim plugins. Look into you OS for similar packages.

Comment: Ubuntu has similar packages, but the selection is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin versioned in git, for example, you can [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) and put the plugin in another dir. Then to update is only a command.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [a bash script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2444). Then you can have it set as a cronjob, and you don't depend on other scripts supporting the ability to update.